# User control is added/removed based on checkbox state. If it's checked the user control added correctly but not working for removal

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried with the following code but still, it adds the user control without any issue but removal is not happening

```
  private void objCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LabelWdTxtBox objLblWdTxtBox = new LabelWdTxtBox();// user control instance created
            objLblWdTxtBox.Controls[1].Name = ((ButtonBase)sender).Text;
            objLblWdTxtBox.Controls[1].Text = ((ButtonBase)sender).Text;
            objLblWdTxtBox.Controls[0].Name = ((ButtonBase)sender).Text;
            if (((CheckBox)sender).CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
            {
                
                flowLayoutUserControl.Controls.Add(objLblWdTxtBox);//adding the user control to panel
            }
            else if (((CheckBox)sender).CheckState == CheckState.Unchecked)
            {  
                     flowLayoutUserControl.Controls.Remove(objLblWdTxtBox);//Removing the user control to panel
                     objLblWdTxtBox.Dispose();  
            }
            flowLayoutUserControl.Refresh();
          // flowLayoutUserControl.ResumeLayout(false);
        }
```

Comment: You're creating a new control instance at the very beggining, so it'll never be within the controls of the FlowLayout. You need to find the control you created earlier and remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the control in the `.Tag` property so you don't have to keep re-creating and disposing of it each time:

```
private void objCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (cb.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        if (cb.Tag == null)
        {
            LabelWdTxtBox objLblWdTxtBox = new LabelWdTxtBox();// user control instance created
            objLblWdTxtBox.Controls[1].Name = ((ButtonBase)sender).Text;
            objLblWdTxtBox.Controls[1].Text = ((ButtonBase)sender).Text;
            objLblWdTxtBox.Controls[0].Name = ((ButtonBase)sender).Text;
            cb.Tag = objLblWdTxtBox;
        }
        flowLayoutUserControl.Controls.Add(cb.Tag); //adding the user control to panel
    }
    else 
    {
        if (cb.Tag != null)
        {  
            flowLayoutUserControl.Controls.Remove(cb.Tag); //Removing the user control to panel
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal to remove the textbox after the user un-checks a checkbox ? Remove textbox completely from the controls or make it invisible?

Assuming there's a checkbox control on the form called `cb_User` and a textbox control `tb_Input` needs to be added/removed from the form

```
private void cb_User_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        var tb_Input = new TextBox();
        tb_Input.Name = "tb_Input";
        this.Controls.Add(tb_Input);
    }
    else
    {
        var tb_Input = this.Controls.Find("tb_Input", true).First();
        this.Controls.Remove(tb_Input);
    }
}
```

The thing that needs to happen is finding the textbox control that was added earlier to the form and removing that instance from the `Form`, which is what `this.Controls.Find()` does - it finds the added control by name (notice it has a name property set)

Comment: @Scratte thank you for the clarification and -1, posted by mistake before adding the actual answer content.

Comment: I see :) I think it will better to not ask any question in an Answer though :)